# Typescript error: "The expected type comes from property 'webPreferences' which is declared here on type 'BrowserWindowConstructorOptions'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to run unredacter by bishop fox. For the life of me, I cannot compile the code. I put it into VScode to debug, and as I have no knowledge of typescript or js (only basic html) I cannot tell what is wrong. VS code says there are two errors, of which I posted screenshots of. Can't find any relevant info on the issue or solution online. I am hoping someone can point me in the direction of how to fix this, since I've been trying to run this program for the better part of a couple weeks. Thanks.

VS Code Debug 1

[image: 1]

```
"message": "Type '{ preload: string; nodeIntegration: false; worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true; contextIsolation: true; }' is not assignable to type 'WebPreferences'.\n  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'worldSafeExecuteJavaScript' does not exist in type 'WebPreferences'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 20,
    "startColumn": 7,
    "endLineNumber": 20,
    "endColumn": 39,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 13642,
            "startColumn": 5,
            "endLineNumber": 13642,
            "endColumn": 19,
            "message": "The expected type comes from property 'webPreferences' which is declared here on type 'BrowserWindowConstructorOptions'",
```

VS Code Debug 2

[image: 2]

```
"message": "Type '{ sandbox: true; webSecurity: true; contextIsolation: true; webviewTag: false; enableRemoteModule: false; allowRunningInsecureContent: false; nodeIntegration: false; nodeIntegrationInWorker: false; nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: false; nativeWindowOpen: false; safeDialogs: true; }' is not assignable to type 'WebPreferences'.\n  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'enableRemoteModule' does not exist in type 'WebPreferences'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 177,
    "startColumn": 7,
    "endLineNumber": 177,
    "endColumn": 32,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 13642,
            "startColumn": 5,
            "endLineNumber": 13642,
            "endColumn": 19,
            "message": "The expected type comes from property 'webPreferences' which is declared here on type 'BrowserWindowConstructorOptions'",
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems you see are related to [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).

You must be using some old code snippet. The property `worldSafeExecuteJavaScript` was [removed from newer versions of Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-worldsafeexecutejavascript); it's now always enabled.

The same happens with `enableRemoteModule`. Remote functionality was extracted from the core library to a separate package. Electron 14 [dropped the type definition](https://github.com/electron/remote/pull/72) for this property but it internally [defaults to false](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-worldsafeexecutejavascript).

You can safely remove both properties from your code.